# problem playing video in totem 14.04

Tags: vlc, totem

I'm having trouble playing videos in ubuntu. After upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 Totem crashes if I move the slider. I am playing a mkv file. It starts playing alright, but if I move the slider totem crashes. 
It used to work like a champ in 13.10 so I know the problem is not in the file.

I switched to VLC and it doesn't seem to have the same problem. 
Any ideas? Is this a known issue?

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get install --reinstall totem`. Also try deleting totem config folder `rm -r -f ~/.config/totem`

Comment: Deleted the folder and reinstalled. Problem persists.

The file plays just fine...until you try to skip ahead using the slider(click or drag). Then totem just crashes and closes with no error dialogs.
Does it generate any kind of error log somwhere?

Comment: Tested this with an mp4 and an avi file and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Totem does not play .mkv files correctly, this is not only an issue for you. For me, it won't even load them, let alone fast forward. Apparently the issue differers with what graphics card and/or drivers you use.

I would definitely reccomend using VLC instead (it IS free as in freedom), it may look ugly and problematic at first, but you can set it to look better and work even better than totem.

There are ways to fix it, but they are usually complex and don't work as good as using VLC out of the box. These fixes don't work for most users anyways, so I wouldn't suggest even trying.

You could also use a different player such as mplayer if you want, but I would definetally reccomend VLC out of the three.